# how to sovle ambiguous column name: nation.n_nationkey in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

how do I solve the problem "ambiguous column name: n_name" and separate supplier and customer's nation?

```
 SELECT count(l_orderkey)
FROM lineitem
INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
INNER JOIN nation ON customer.c_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey 
INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
INNER JOIN region ON nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
WHERE n_name = "UNITED STATES" AND r_name = "AFRICA"
```

Comment: Each table must be assigned with an alias which is unique within the query.

Comment: Add an alias for each line of `nation`. For example, you ca add alias `a` in the first case and `b` in the second case: `INNER JOIN nation a ON customer.c_nationkey = a.n_nationkey`.

Answer (score 1):

you can split the query in two parts :

- One for Customer count
- And the seconde one for Supplier count

And after that make a Sum of the count's to get the final count result for the line order key as bellow :

```
select Sum(Result.counts) from (
SELECT count(l_orderkey)  AS counts 
FROM lineitem
INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
INNER JOIN nation ON customer.c_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
WHERE customer.c_nationkey = "UNITED STATES" 
union all
SELECT count(l_orderkey) AS counts 
FROM lineitem
INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey
INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
WHERE supplier.s_nationkey = "AFRICA"
)Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(l_orderkey)
FROM lineitem
INNER JOIN supplier ON lineitem.l_suppkey = supplier.s_suppkey
INNER JOIN nation ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
INNER JOIN nation nation2 ON supplier.s_nationkey = nation2.n_nationkey
INNER JOIN region region2 ON nation2.n_regionkey = region2.r_regionkey
INNER JOIN region ON nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
INNER JOIN orders ON lineitem.l_orderkey = orders.o_orderkey
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.o_custkey = customer.c_custkey
INNER JOIN nation nation1 ON customer.c_nationkey = nation1.n_nationkey
WHERE nation1.n_name = 'UNITED STATES' AND region2.r_name = 'AFRICA';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).